# A manga about someone reincarnating over and over again in order to pass a test

Tags: story-identification, manga, isekai

It's about a guy who keeps reincarnating over and over again because he kept failing the grading system. If you fail you keep on doing it, and if you pass you get sent back to Earth. The manga right now has over 140 chapters. This was about a year ago. I didn't bookmark it. I tried chatGPT and searching for the manga everywhere.

Can someone tell me what it is?

Comment: You can accept a correct answer by clicking on the checkmark by the voting buttons, as per the [tour].

Answer (score 6):

With some loose interpretation of word "reincarnation" it matches "[FFF-class trash hero](https://myanimelist.net/manga/147463/FFF-Class_Trashero)".

Protagonist is summoned to defeat Demon Lord. He defeats him, but system gives low marks for "heroic behavior" and he starts from scratch. This repeats a few times but finally manages pass while still being trash person. Of course story doesn't end even then.

I saw there is also supposedly similar story "[Is this hero for real](https://myanimelist.net/manga/149906/Is_This_Hero_for_Real)", but didn't read it.

Comment: thanks, that is the one i was looking for

Comment: @SherielLumXiangYuNorthvist Nice, feel free to upvote/accept answer :)